# Magento 2.4.4 REST API short description post

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I'm trying to import the short description with Postman.
No matter how i try I always get an error.

I'm using following URL /rest/english/V1/products/

The shop has to different view_codes english and german.

Can someone send me a postman sample?

Im trying with following body:

```
{
  "product": {
      "sku": "VBP_008",
      "name": "Vintage Backpack45654scs654",
      "attribute_set_id": 4,
      "short_description": "TEST",
      "price": 32,
      "view_code": "english",
      "status": 1,
      "visibility": 1,
      "type_id": "simple",
      "weight": "30"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Wayx

Answer (score 1):

Add short description under custom_attributes in your JSON payload.

```
{
      "product": {
        "sku": "MS-Dime",
        "name": "Dime Tee Small",
        "attribute_set_id": 4,
        "price": 25,
        "status": 1,
        "visibility": 1,
        "type_id": "simple",
        "weight": "0.6",
        "extension_attributes": {
            "category_links": [
                {
                    "position": 0,
                    "category_id": "11"
                },
                {
                    "position": 1,
                    "category_id": "12"
                },
                {
                    "position": 2,
                    "category_id": "16"
                }
            ],
            "stock_item": {
                "qty": "10",
                "is_in_stock": true
            }
        },
        "custom_attributes": [
            {
                "attribute_code": "description",
                "value": "The Dime Tee is soft, comfortable and durable. You will love the way you look in this tailored tee shirt."
    
            },
                {
                "attribute_code": "short_description",
                "value": "The Dime Tee is soft."
                
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
                "value": "2"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "material",
                "value": "148"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "pattern",
                "value": "196"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "color",
                "value": "52"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "size",
                "value": "168"
            }
        ]
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! I have another question: Is there any chance of importing rtf text to description?

Comment: @wayx Please accept the answer above if it has solved your initial question and ask a separate question for importing RTF to the description.